# О количестве времени, большом количестве времени

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли так говорить о времени? Не говорят же о количестве возраста или количестве веса, высоты, объёма, тепла, давления?

Answer (score 3):

**Количество ― это универсальная категория,** **а возраст, масса, и прочие величины уже включают в себя это понятие.**

**Время** ― мера длительности всего происходящего, существующего, измеряемая секундами, минутами, часами, сутками и т.п. , то есть дискретными отрезками, количество - это естественная мера величины времени (**ВЕЛИЧИНА**, 2. **Количественное** выражение физического признака какого-л. явления).

**КОЛИЧЕСТВО**, -а; ср. 1. Категория, характеризующая предметы и явления внешнего мира со стороны величины, объёма, числа, степени развития. **ВОЗРАСТ**,  1. Количество прожитых лет; период в жизни человека, животного. **МАССА**,  1. Количество, объём вещества, составляющего, образующего тот или иной предмет;

Comment: Не увидел живого заключительного слова, к сожалению, хотя можно предполагать: так говорить можно и нужно. Но разве измеряются не интервалы времени, и разве длительность не есть лишь один из синонимов? А если относится ко времени как понятию, грубо говоря: время — деньги?